# PCA plotting - What is the difference between ggfortify and ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I'm new to PCA. I'm plotting the scores using `autoplot` from `ggfortify` and `ggplot`. Both have the same shape but have different values for the x and y axes. Eg. `autoplot` goes from -0.2 to 0.2 in the y-axis, and `ggplot` goes from -0.6 to -0.6. The points on the graphs look the exact same. Only the values of the axes changed. Why is that?

Edit:
I can't really give the full data here as it's very long. I tried these two:

```
library(ggfortify)
pca.data <- prcomp(my_data)
autoplot(pca.data)
```

and

```
my_dataframe <- data.frame(Sample = rownames(pca.data$x),
                                       X = pca.data$x[,1],
                                       Y = pca.data$x[,2])
ggplot(data = my_dataframe, aes(x=X, y=Y, label=Sample)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("PC1") +
  ylab("PC2") +
  ggtitle("PCA Graph")
```

Comment: Hello, I think you will have to be more specific and maybe provide a reproducible example: for me, if `res <- prcomp(mtcars)`, both `ggplot2::autoplot(res)`  and `ggfortify:::autoplot.prcomp(res)` give the same result.

Comment: I'm using R version 4.1.1, ggfortify version 0.4.12 and ggplot2 version 3.3.5

Comment: @VincentGuillemot Updated my question. I'm running the latest versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_pca.html), autoplot scales in the same way as the `biplot()` function. If you don't want it to, you can instead use:

```
autoplot(pca.data, scale=0)
```

which (except for axis labels) gives the same at the `ggplot` command that you used.